# Used the same method of importing but got AttributeError

Tags: python

I was coding and was using a module I've used in the past. Previously, I imported modules like this and created functions with it:

```
import module as m
def example():
    m.do_something()
```

And it worked just fine.

I don't understand why when I import the same module this comes out:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'do_something'
```

But I'm using the same module before AND used the same method of importing. What's going on?

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you have a version of `module.py` in the local directory, but you are expecting to import `module.py` from elsewhere on your python path. The local version will shadow the other, and if the local version does not contain the `do_something()` function you will see the error that you show.

For example if you had a file named `urllib.py` in your local directory and tried `import urllib`, the local version will be imported, not the one from the standard library.

To fix this, rename the local file to avoid the name clash.